# Returning Left "Error" is consuming template

Tags: daml

```
XYZManager.daml:
nonconsuming choice CallingChoice: Either Text (ContractId XYZ)
    exercise (contractIdXYZ) CalledChoice with ...

XYZ.daml:
choice CalledChoice: Either Text (ContractId XYZ)
     with ...
    if conditionFails do
        return Left "Error"
    else do
        continue execution of other lines`
```

In the above code if "CalledChoice" returns Left "Error" then XYZ template is being consumed even though we are returning Left. How to handle this by handling required validations.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of a choice will never result in that choice being treated as aborted. If you want to abort a choice you can call the `abort : Text -> Update a` function, e.g., in your example:

```
choice CalledChoice : ContractId XYZ
  with …
  do if conditionFails do
       abort "Error"
     else do
       continue execution of other lines
```

There is also an `assert` function that will call abort if the condition does not hold. That works quite nicely for your example:

```
choice CalledChoice : ContractId XYZ
  with …
  do assert (not conditionFails)
     continue execution of other lines
```

If you want to include a custom error message, you can use `assertMsg "Error" (not conditionFails)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can i return list of errors as a response to JS binding code? This can help us showing exact validation message on UI.

Comment: `abort` (and thereby also all wrappers around `abort` like `assert`) only accepts a single `Text` value. If you have a list of errors you first have to convert them to a single `Text`, e.g., by calling `show` on the list.